# Can messages sent from Solace JCSMP be consumed in services written in other languages

Tags: amqp, solace, solace-mq

What exactly is Solace JCSMP?

Is it just a more suited JMS API for Solace? What kind of other benefits does it have?

For example, I would need to create a Java application using SolaceMQ that needs to send/receive messages over to/from AMQP protocol so that all different microservices written in different languages would be able to consume them. Is JCSMP right for that? or is it just another JMS API that it only works between Java applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly is Solace JCSMP?

JCSMP is the Classic Java API for Solace's SMF (Solace Message Format) protocol. Note that Solace recently introduced a more modern messaging API for java devs using their event brokers that is just referred to as the "PubSub+ Messaging API for Java". If you are new to Solace and using Java it may make sense to use that instead of JCSMP.

> Is it just a more suited JMS API for Solace? What kind of other benefits does it have?

JCSMP allows developers to take advantage of the full feature set offered by the Solace Broker whereas the Solace JMS implementation only covers the features defined in the JMS specification itself. For example, use of Solace features such as Replay or having Queues subscribe to Topics are not programmatically possible via the JMS API and would have to be done administratively if using JMS.

> For example, I would need to create a Java application using SolaceMQ that needs to send/receive messages over to/from AMQP protocol so that all different microservices written in different languages would be able to consume them. Is JCSMP right for that? or is it just another JMS API that it only works between Java applications?

Solace PubSub+ Event Brokers provide protocol translation between any of the protocols supported by the broker. It doesn't matter whether you are using SMF (which both Solace JMS and JCSMP use), MQTT, AMQP 1.0, etc. or what programming language you are using. For example when you send a message using JCSMP you can receive it using a Java app using JMS, a Python app using AMQP and a Go app using MQTT. The Solace Event Broker even has support for calling a RESTful webhook using it (Check out Solace "Rest Delivery Endpoints"). Just a heads up that if you're using headers you'll want to checkout the Solace docs to see how they're mapped during protocol translation.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!